# Session android php

Tags: php, mysql

I put my session in my login php like this, and I also put session in my insert data php but my username for insert data table still blank, and the app also toast a message say undefined index username. My login table has user_id, username, password and email while table insert data has id, username and name. I want the data of username in table insert data is get from username of table login.

Login Php

```
<?php 

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';


$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $db = new DbOperations(); 
    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username and password=$password"; 

    if($db->userLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $user = $db->getUserByUsername($_POST['username']);
        $response['error'] = false; 
        $response['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
        $response['email'] = $user['email'];
        $response['username'] = $user['username'];
         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];                
}else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Invalid username or password";          
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}
echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

Insert data php

```
<?php 
require_once('dbConnect.php');
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username']; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Data (username, name) VALUES 
('$username','$name')";


}  //Executing query to database
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'Insert Successfully';
}else{
echo 'You already insert data';



mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Is my insert data php has problem? please help me thank you very much.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/reward/redeemReward.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/reward/redeemReward.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/reward/redeemReward.php on line 15
```

Comment: Database using localhost xampp

Comment: At what line you get that error (undefined index username ) , maybe the name of the input is wrong on HTML side .

Comment: The insert data php , line $username = $_SESSION['username'];  and my one is application using android studio and i use php and mysql as my database

Comment: so that session was not set , try `print_r($_SESSION);`  before that line to check.

Comment: You need to put `session_start();` first before you use `$_SESSION`

Comment: I add this line before line $username = $_SESSION['username']; but still same come out same message

Comment: I got put session_start(); in my insert data php

Comment: `session_start();` should be called at the top of script before any output .

Comment: top of script mean where?

Comment: Mean after  `<?php ` in every file you need to use sessions in .

Comment: i try already but still got error and i will post the error on my question